# How to determine if optional arguments are passed in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parameters, optional-parameters

If I have the following method in Ruby:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2 = "bar")
  puts arg1
  puts arg2
end
```

Is there a way of determining if a user passed a value in for `arg2` within the method? Obviously I could just add `if arg2 == "bar"` to the method, but this doesn't catch the case where the user manually passed in `"bar"` herself. Of course, I could set the default to be something that no user would ever pass in, but then that gets pretty ugly pretty quickly.

Is there anything elegant out there?

Comment: Am I correct in my understanding that, for your example, you want to know if `foo` can determine whether the call to it was `foo(arg1)` or `foo(arg1, "bar")`?

Comment: Yes, this is it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is possible. Consider the following:

```
class Test
  def method(a,b=1)
    local_variables.each do |var|
          puts "Setting #{var} to #{eval var.to_s}"
    end
  end
end
```

And then try to call `method` on an instance of `Test`:

```
?> t.method(1)
Setting a to 1
Setting b to 1
=> [:a, :b]

?> t.method(1,2)
Setting a to 1
Setting b to 2
=> [:a, :b]

?> t.method(1,1)
Setting a to 1
Setting b to 1
=> [:a, :b]
```

Those do not distinguish how the method was called.

So I would suggest @sawa's approach mixed with the following:

```
raise ArgumentError, "Too many arguments" if args.length > 2
```

since you seem to want to limit the parameters to 2 and @sawa's approach allows for an undefined number.

This is an unorthodox approach to an unorthodox requirement, so just make sure the clients of your method are aware of how the API works.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. In my actual implementation I'm just going to make the second parameter default to `nil` (as the user will never pass `nil` to it) and then swap `nil` with the "default" value within the method, but I was curious if there was a better way.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for iterating through `local_variables`, rather than just referencing `a` and `b`.  Either way, doesn't this just show what we already know?

Answer (score 24):

```
def foo(arg1, arg2 = (arg2_not_passed = true; "bar"))
  puts arg1
  puts arg2
  puts 'arg2 was passed' unless arg2_not_passed
end
```

Comment: Interesting; Would appreciate if you could help understand `a = (b = true; "something")`

Comment: It's just a Ruby expression. It first sets `b` to `true`, and then, as a new statement, executes the string `"something"`. The value of the whole parenthetical will be the value of the last statement, so it still sets `a` to `"something"` as expected.

I believe you want this to be `arg2 = (arg2_was_passed = false; "bar")`, however, not `true`.

Comment: This is genius!

Answer (score 3):

```
def foo(*args)
  case args.length
  when 1
    # arg2 was not given
    arg1, arg2 = args.first, "bar"
    ...
  when 2
    # arg2 was given
    arg1, arg2 = args
    ...
  else
    raise ArgumentError
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

One way (not elegant but fun) is to make the default value such that it has a unique `object_id`. It wil not work if default value is an immutable object like integer.

```
def c
  @c ||= "bar"
end

def fun(a,b = c)   
     puts  b.object_id == c.object_id ? "default" : "user" 
end

fun "foo"
#=> "default"

fun "foo", "bar"
#=> "user"
```

Comment: I like it! Foiled again by those pesky immutables.

Comment: This is how Rubinius does it, in many of its method implementations. In YARV, JRuby, etc. they are implemented in C, Java, etc. and have access to the internal implementation of the parameter list and thus can check how many arguments were passed. But in Rubinius, many of those methods are implemented in pure Ruby, with no special functionality whatsoever, and so they have to resort to tricks like this. In Rubinius, there is a special `undefined` method which returns an object with an unforgeable `object_id` and within the method you can then do `undefined.equals?(b)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution! Suppose we want:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2 = 42)
```

Then we would instead write:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2 = [42,KEY])
```

If `agr2 == [42,KEY]`, we conclude that the calling method did not pass a second argument, in which case the default of `42` applies.  If `arg2` is anything else, `arg2` was passed.  Simple!

I know what you're thinking: what if the calling program were to actually pass `[42,KEY]`?  I have that figured out too: `KEY = rand(100000000000000)`.

I would like to add one more thing.  I am in principal opposed to doing so, but I know if I don't I will receive so many downvotes that my reputation will go negative.  So here it is: :-)

Comment: I just thought about similar approach and found out you already answered. I'm wondering though why are you against using this approach. For example what bad is to write a method like `def mymethod(param1, param2 = "not specified by user")`? Then I can have in the body `param2 = "default value" if param2 == "not specified by user"`.

Comment: I have no objection in principle (though others might). I just think it's a bit kludgy, and that it's probably better to restructure the code to avoid the need to answer the question.