# How to pass optional named arguments in Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby

Is there a way for an argument to be truly optional so I know if it was set by caller or not?

Having an argument use `nil` as the default does not work because there is no way to know if the caller passed `nil` or it is the default value for the argument.

Before named arguments, in Ruby 1.9, using an options hash:

```
def foo(options = {})
  # …
  bar(options)
end

def bar(options = {})      
  puts options.fetch(:name, ‘unknown’) # => 'unknown'
end
```

With Ruby 2.0 named arguments:

```
def foo(name: nil)
  # …
  bar(name: name)
end

def bar(name: ‘unknown’)
  # …
  puts name # => nil, since nil is explicitly passed from `foo`
end
```

Comment: The title and the question do not seem to match. Also, it is not clear what your codes are showing.

Comment: I guess my point is that there is no such thing as an optional argument, the next best thing is to set the default to `nil`. But the problem is that passing nil explicitly as an argument does not invoke the default.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your title to better reflect your question.

Comment: I believe the question posed in the first sentence was answered about a year ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472413/how-to-determine-if-optional-arguments-are-passed-in-ruby). Some interesting answers. @sawa, did you forget that one of them was yours?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Probably the best way to  go would be:

```
def bar(name: nil)
  name ||= 'unknown'
  puts name
end
```

Comment: This is the solution I also came to shortly after posting the question, I'll see if anything else comes up before accepting.

Comment: This behaves differently than using `fetch`, as explicitly passing `nil`, or `false`, is not treated the same way.

Answer (score 4):

I would assume from you example that you are not using `name` in `foo` but want to pass it along.

You should use the catch all for named arguments instead:

```
def foo(**named)
  # …
  bar(**named)
end

def bar(name: 'unknown')
  # …
  puts name
end

foo # => 'unknown'
foo(name: 'baz') # => 'baz'
```

Note that this not interfere with other arguments (named or not), so you if you had other arguments for `foo`:

```
def foo(what, other: 42, **named)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear why you want to know if the argument was provided or not. The most useful reason to know, is because you want to require one of your optional arguments. If that's the reason, then starting with Ruby 2.1, you can get what you want.

```
def foo(a:,b:nil,c:3)
 [a, b, c]
end

foo a: 1, b: 2, c: 3
#=> [1, 2, 3]
foo a: 1, b: 2
#=> [1, 2, 3]
foo a: 1
#=> [1, nil, 3]
foo
#ArgumentError: missing keyword: a
```

Comment: I think the issue is `foo(a: 1, b: nil) => [1, nil, 3]` and `foo(a: 1) => [1, nil, 3]`. Is there a way for `foo` to know which way it was called?

Comment: Correct, I understand that is the issue. The solution is to not give a default value (which is valid starting Ruby 2.1). By not giving a default you are insisting that they provide one (the one they provide can be nil). I used the `a` parameter as an example of this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an "undefined" value as the default to tell it apart from a nil:

```
Undefined = Object.new.freeze

def foo(a: Undefined)
  puts a
end

foo(a: nil) # => "nil"
foo # => "#<Object:0x000056004b29a058>"
```

If you use [dry-rb](https://dry-rb.org), then you can use `Dry::Core::Constants::Undefined` ([source](https://github.com/dry-rb/dry-core/blob/master/lib/dry/core/constants.rb#L41)), which provides a few extras:

```
Undefined = Dry::Core::Constants::Undefined

def foo(a: Undefined)
  puts a
end

foo(a: nil) # => "nil"
foo # => "Undefined"
```