# Determine whether argument was default or explicitly passed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arguments

I have a helper method like this:

```
def table_row(record, field, custom_value = nil)
  content_tag(:tr) do
    concat content_tag(:th, field.to_s.humanize)
    concat content_tag(:td, custom_value || record.public_send(field))
  end
end
```

This lets me call that method like this:

```
<%= table_row(@user, :name) %>
<%= table_row(@user, 'Day they were born', @user.birth_date&.strftime("%A")) %>
```

The problem is, with the line above if `@user.birth_date` is nil then the code will try to call `@user.public_send('Day they were born')`.

How do I tell the difference between the `nil` from the default `custom_value` and `nil` from the `custom_value` being explicitly defined as nil when called?

Comment: Answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472413/how-to-determine-if-optional-arguments-are-passed-in-ruby) SO question provides a range of ways of dealing with this issue. However, all require that `custom_value = nil` in your example be modified in one way or another.

Comment: Not an answer to the question but I would recommend just using a `respond_to?` check instead. Your issue is that `nil` is a singleton so it is impossible to determine a difference between `nil` default and `nil` passed because they are the same exact object.